# How to use this Javascript checkAlphaNumeric() with HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, validation, passwords

I am stumped. I have the following code and cannot get it to work right. I'm kind of using a password or email validation event of onkeyup, but I really just want it to work if I click on submit. My form is already using validateForm() and checkPass(). I just need to get this to work.

```
// *********** ALPHA-Numeric check ***************************
    function checkAlphaNumeric()
    {  
       var passw = document.getElementById("_password");
       var mystring=new String(passw)
       var authpassword = document.getElementById("AuthPass");

      if(mystring.search(/[0-9]+/)==-1) // Check at-least one number
        {
           authpassword.innerHTML = "<span class='smaller'>*Password must be 8 characters, 1 letter, and 1 number!</span>!";
           return false; 
        } else {
           count++; 
           document.getElementById("err_password").innerHTML="";
         }

      if(mystring.search(/[A-Z]+/)==-1 && mystring.search(/[a-z]+/)==-1) // Check at-least one character
        {
           authpassword.innerHTML = "<span class='smaller'>*Password must be 8 characters, 1 letter, and 1 number!</span>!";
           return false;
        } else {  count++; 
           document.getElementById("err_password").innerHTML="";
          }
      } //*** END FUNCTION
 HTML CODE IS BELOW
 <input id="_password" type="password" name="password" autocomplete="off" size="40"      onkeyup="checkAlphaNumeric(); return false;"><span id="AuthPass" class="AuthPass" style="font-size: smaller; color:red;""></span>
```

Comment: What is not working right exactly?

Comment: `var mystring=new String(passw)`. What the... ? Who told you to do this `:P` (it should be `var mystring = passw.value;`)